# Wirecloud xml parser for Widgets

Tags: xml, widget, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Has something changed in the parser for widgets between version 0.8.4 and version 0.9.1? We recently updated and now we cannot upload our .wgt files anymore. The following error gets displayed: `Error uploading the following components: TestWidget.wgt: Error parsing config.xml descriptor file: No valid parser found`.

The exact same file works just fine with WireCloud v 0.8.4.
This problem does not occure when uploading operators, they work just fine.

Here is our config.xml that worked with 0.8.4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Template xmlns="http://wirecloud.conwet.fi.upm.es/ns/template#">
    <Catalog.ResourceDescription>
        <Vendor>Example Com</Vendor>
        <Name>widget.chart</Name>
        <Version>0.0.1</Version>
        <DisplayName>Chart</DisplayName>
        <Author>newbird</Author>
        <Mail>newbird@ecample.com</Mail>
        <Description>A chart</Description>
        <ImageURI>images/arrow.png</ImageURI>
        <iPhoneImageURI>images/arrow.png</iPhoneImageURI>
        <WikiURI>doc/index.html</WikiURI>
    </Catalog.ResourceDescription>
    <Platform.Wiring>
        <InputEndpoint name="data" type="text" label="Data"
                       action_label="data" description="Insert data here"
                       friendcode="text"/>
    </Platform.Wiring>
    <Platform.Link>
        <XHTML href="index.html" content-type="text/html" cacheable="false"
               use-platform-style="true"/>
    </Platform.Link>
    <Platform.Rendering width="3" height="8"/>
</Template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this format was deprecated on WireCloud 0.7.0 (although we didn't provide release notes for that version, sorry), and was removed in [WireCloud 0.9.1](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/releases/tag/0.9.1)

You can convert your widget descriptions from this format to the current one by executing the following command (using WireCloud 0.9.0 or bellow):

```
$ wirecloud-admin convert -d xml config.xml config.xml
```

Comment: When trying to convert the config.xml listed above the following error gets prompted: `No handlers could be found for logger "rdflib.term"
Error: No valid parser found`.
Is there an example config.xml that demonstrates the new template? In the WireCloud sources I was only able to locate examples using the old template.

Comment: My fault, I did not read your instructions carefully, had to take the 0.8.4 version of wirecloud to transform the xml config.